# How to add Kendo UI HTML helpers to my ASP.net MVC 4 project?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Simple question: I've installed Telerik DevCraft Ultimate on my workstation.  I've looked at the examples showing the use of the Kendo UI HTML helpers.

What reference do I add to my project to be able to use them?

Answer (score 8):

Configure your ASP.NET MVC layout page to include the Kendo UI Web JavaScript and CSS files:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.default.min.css")">
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

Add a reference to the Kendo.Mvc.UI namespace to your web.config. Then the Kendo HtmlHelper extension would be availble in your views. Rebuild your project after adding the namespace to the web.config (required for Visual Studio to show intellisense for Kendo.Mvc.UI).

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
             <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
         </namespaces>
     </pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Use any Kendo UI HtmlHelper extension

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("Birthday"))
```

more details at http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction

Comment: For some reason, I never could get Telerik tutorial to work in my project.  I can get it to work by using @using Kendo.Mvc.UI at the top of pages I want to use control on, but can't get web.config to recognize it.  I was spending too much time troubleshooting, so for now I'll just keep doing using Kendo.Mvc.UI at top of views.

Comment: Go to web.config and  introduce namespace
under the <namespaces> section add   <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" /> -> in two location 
    a) in the root of the web.config solution then 
    b)then in the second web.config roots of the view folder --(see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Gsy18e1cCM )