# Do I need to include jquery with kendo

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm using the Kendo ASP.NET MVC Wrapper and was wondering do I need to include the jquery? I really want to use a jquery plugin e.g. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/ and was wondering if I have to include jquery to use the plugin or would it not be necessary as jquery is already included in the kendo stuff?

Vince.

Comment: you need jQuery for Kendo. see [how to configure Kendo in MVC Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16049425/942855)

Answer (score 1):

Check your markup to see if it's referenced.

Comment: I see it has <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/jquery.min.js")"></script> and I also included @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") bundle which is the same version e.g. 1.9.1 now the plugin does work when both are there. If I remove the kendo one it breaks kendo but the colorbox works. If I remove the jquery one it has no effect and the colorbox still does not work.