# kendo grid ajax bind not work

Tags: c#, ajax, razor, kendo-grid

I follow the kendo demo, and I check the data was return list of data to view, but finally the grid have not display any row.

View

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductListModel>()

    .Name("grid")  
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("RowTemplate_Read","Product").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))

    )        
    .Scrollable()
)
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult RowTemplate_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)

        { 
            var productList = GetAllProduct().Select(e => new ProductListModel{Name = e.NameChi, Id = e.Id });


            return Json(productList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Here is the page and error view:

http://postimg.org/image/dx0cyu5n1/
http://postimg.org/image/9ptdejo9t/

---

17-Nov-2013
Finally I find out the problem is DTO, I can not directly use it for binding, Anyone can tell me the reason?!

DTO CODE:

```
public class ProductDTO : DTO
    {

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string NameChi { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string NameEng { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string DescriptionChi { get; set; }

        public string DescriptionEng { get; set; }

        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product_Brand")]
        public BrandDTO Brand { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Brand")]
        public int BrandId { get; private set; }

        public string MainPhotoPath { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductCategory")]
        public int ProductCategoryId { get; private set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product_ProductCategory")]
        public ProductCategoryDTO ProductCategory { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductType")]
        public int ProductTypeId { get; private set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product_ProductType")]
        public ProductTypeDTO ProductType { get; set; }

        public  List<PhotoDTO> PhotosPaths { get; set; }

        public  List<TagDTO> Tags { get; set; }

        public  List<GalleryDTO> Galleries { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: http 404 error means that the page is not available, seems you are missing some scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Kendo UI HTML helpers to my ASP.net MVC 4 project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046697/how-to-add-kendo-ui-html-helpers-to-my-asp-net-mvc-4-project)

Comment: @MichaC The jQuery map is not relevant to this issue. user2998970 please can you post where you include your Kendo scripts in the view or layout?

Comment: re @MichaC , that is partial view.